# Find the corresponding td of second for spanned columns of the first row

Tags: jquery

I have table structure as

```
<table> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td id='td1' rowspan="2"></td> 
            <td id='td2' rowspan="2"></td>
            <td id='td3' rowspan="2"></td>
            <td id='td4' colspan="2"></td>
            <td id='td5' colspan="2"></td>
            <td id='td6' rowspan="2"></td>
            <td id='td7' rowspan="2"></td>
            <td id='td8' colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id='td9'></td> 
            <td id='td10'></td>
            <td id='td11'></td> 
            <td id='td12'></td>
            <td id='td13'></td> 
            <td id='td14'></td>
            <td id='td15'></td> 
            <td id='td16'></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ></td> 
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td> 
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td> 
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td> 
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td> 
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to find from thead second row all the td corresponding to the first row td which were spanned with colpan.

I had tried find the childslength and tried some formula to calculate the same but not working

Comment: Mmmh.. I think your question would be clearer with an example. For instance, what is the expected result for the code above? Thanks!

Comment: I Want when is i have td4 i should get td9 and td10 from second row ,  similarly td5, td11,td12 and for td8, td13,td14....  Basically i want all the columns of the second row which are spanned for the first row

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this:

I used the index of the elements and not their ID, so you can change them to whatever you want.

```
$("tr:eq(0) td[colspan]").click(function(){
    var myIndex = $(this).index();
    var myColspan = parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'));
    var startingFrom = 0;
    var previous = $("tr:eq(0) td:lt(" + myIndex + ")[colspan]").each(function(){
        startingFrom += parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'));
    });
    // This is the list of results.
    var elements = $("tr:eq(1) td").slice(startingFrom, startingFrom + myColspan);
    // Just for checking
    elements.each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });


});
```

I just attached the functionality to the 'click' event for demo purpose.

Check out my Fiddle for a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/K3pA2/

**Reference:**

- **Using eq selector**: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/
- **Using lt selector**: http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/
- **Using each function**: http://api.jquery.com/each/
- **Using slice function**: http://api.jquery.com/slice/
- **Fiddle on using selectors and attribute matching**: http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/hafvf/